# Recognise a specific sound (not speech)

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio

What kind of ml model would one use to recognise a specific sound to roughly compare and recognise waveforms (I have the data I need).

I could only find stuff about recognising speech but not a specific sound.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) problem and there are multiple ways to solve it.

You'll need to train a model on a dataset representative of sounds you expect. Assuming you have the data, you can choose any multiclass classification algorithm depending on training time, prediction time, accuracy you need.

One critical step is to process the data to fit into the classifier and there is also a lot of methods you can use but for audio processing most will rely on a frequency representation (Fourier Transform). MEL Spectrogram<sup>[2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7324337),[3](https://towardsdatascience.com/audio-deep-learning-made-simple-part-2-why-mel-spectrograms-perform-better-aad889a93505)</sup> seems to yield good results well here. It's also possible to represent the spectrogram as images and use image classification methods.

As you mention python, and if you absolutely don't know where to start, I'd suggest to use a deep learning library like [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/).

CNN<sup>[2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7324337)</sup> seems to yield good result for this particular task.

The pytorch documentation contains a [beginner tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) for image or audio classification.

To recap, you'll need to:

1. Obtain and label data for each type of sound you want to classify.
2. Preprocess audio using a frequency representation.
3. Train a model on the data.
4. Use the model to predict class on new data.